# Why is there ```No value provided for required arguments 'app_path'``` when I try to create a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, path, project, new-operator

(this is my first post, sorry if i make a mistake),

In Iterm2 I put :

`rails _5.2.3_ new -d postgresql`

And the terminal answers:

`No value provided for required arguments 'app_path'`

I opened the .zshrc file and tried to figure out if the problem comes from this file and searched for the keyword `PATH`but couldn't figure out if a path is wrong or not. Does the problem is on the .zshrc file ? Where is the problem and how to solve it ?

Here is my .zshrc file

```
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/thibaultguichard/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="simple"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
git
bundler
dotenv
osx
rake
rbenv
ruby
zsh-syntax-highlighting
zsh-autosuggestions
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
# export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

# SYSTEM ALIAS
alias cls='clear'                                   # Clear the terminal
alias c='clear'                                     # Clear the terminal
alias h='history'                                   # Print bash command history
alias ll='ls -l'                                    # List files in a list
alias la='ls -al'                                   # List files in a list with hidden files

# GIT ALIAS
alias gitalias='alias | grep git'                   # Show all alias for git (if you have OH MY ZSH you have lots of other aliases)
alias gs='git status'                               # Show the working tree status
alias gcl='git clone'                               # Clone a repository into a new directory
alias gpush='git push'                              # Update remote refs along with associated objects
alias gpull='git pull'                              # Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch
alias ga='git add'                                  # Add file contents to the index
alias gcm='git commit -m'                           # Record changes to the repository
alias gco='git checkout'                            # Switch branches or restore working tree files
alias gbr='git branch'                              # List, create, or delete branches
alias glog='git log'                                # Show commit logs
alias greset='git reset'                            # Reset current HEAD to the specified state

# BUNDLE ALIAS
alias bundlealias='alias | grep bundle'             # Show all alias for bundle
alias bi='bundle install'                           # Install the current environment to the system
alias bl='bundle list'                              # List all gem in GEMFILE and version
alias bu='bundle update'                            # Update the current environment (update gem)
alias ba='bundle add'                               # Command for add multiple gem in gemfile and launch a bundle update

# HEROKU ALIAS
alias herokualias='alias | grep heroku'             # Show all alias for Heroku
alias hrdbs='heroku run rake db:seed'
alias hrdbm='heroku run rails db:migrate'
alias hrc='heroku create'
alias hrrc='heroku run rails console'
alias hrbi='heroku run bundle install'
alias hrupdate='heroku update'                      # Update the Heroku CLI
alias hrpsql='heroku psql'                          # Open a psql shell to the database
alias hrlogs='heroku logs'                          # Display recent log output
alias hrlog='heroku logs'                           # Display recent log output
# APT ALIAS
alias aptalias='alias | grep apt'                   # show all alias for apt
alias update='sudo apt update -y'                   # Update list of available packages
alias upgrade='sudo apt upgrade -y'                 # Upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
alias full-upgrade='sudo apt full-upgrade -y'       # Upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages
alias dist-upgrade='sudo apt dist-upgrade -y'       # Upgrade your distributtion system with sudo and ask yes
alias autoremove='sudo apt autoremove'              # Remove automatically all unused packages
# RAILS ALIAS
alias railsalias='alias | grep rails'               # Show all alias for rails

### RAILS CREATION
alias nr='rails _5.2.3_ new'
alias nrp='rails _5.2.3_ new -d postgresql'
### RAILS OTHER
alias rc='rails console'
alias rd='rails destroy'
alias rp='rails plugin'
alias ru='rails runner'
alias rs='rails server'
alias rsd='rails server --debugger'
alias rr='rails routes'
### RAILS GENERATE
alias rg='rails generate'
alias rgmigration='rails generate migration'
alias rgmodel='rails generate model'
alias rgscaffold='rails generate scaffold'
alias rgc='rails generate controller'
### RAILS DATABASE
alias rdb='rails dbconsole'                         # Database console in the database of your Rails APP
alias rdbd='rails db:drop'
alias rdbc='rails db:create'
alias rdbs='rails db:seed'
alias rdbm='rails db:migrate'
alias rdbms='rails db:migrate status'
alias rdbr='rails db:rollback'

#OTHERS ALIAS
alias path='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'                 # Print all PATH environnement in a list
alias now='date +"%T"'                              # Get the time now
alias nowdate='date +"%d-%m-%Y"'                    # Get the Date
alias vi='vim'
alias svim='sudo vim'                               # Launch Vim with sudo
alias edit='vim'
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify a name for your new project.

Try with `rails _5.2.3_ new NameOfTheApp -d postgresql`

It should work. (: